# How to XML serialize a class Type using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I'm trying to XML serialize a class after getting the class through reflection. Can anyone suggest me the exact method. Below is my code.

```
Assembly myassembly = Assembly.LoadFile(myassemblypath);
List<Type> types = myassembly .GetTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(myType));
foreach (Type item in types)
{
 dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(item);
 using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
 new XmlSerializer(item.GetType()).Serialize(writer, instance);
string xmlEncodedList = writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
Console.WriteLine(xmlEncodedList);
 }
}
```

This code is not working, it gives me exception.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to Serialize it that easily. You might just want to write an XDoc yourself. Would be helpful to tell us what exception you're getting exactly, though...

Comment: What is the exception and which line causes that exception?

Comment: item.GetType() as it returns the System.RuntimeType

Answer (score 0):

as you are getting system.RuntimeType exception , for getting actual type you need to unwrap actual type from RuntimeType , that will resolve your issue.

following is code to unwrape actual type

```
 var runTimeObj = Activator.
               CreateInstance(assemblyName, assemblyName + "." + className);
 //T is generic type as i m using genric
 //but point of interest here is unwrap method to get actual type
 var dataProvider = (T)runTimeObj.Unwrap();
```

---

one more example

```
  ObjectHandle handle = Activator.CreateInstance("PersonInfo", "Person");
  Object p = handle.Unwrap();
  Type t = p.GetType();
```

---

one more problem with you code use of `dynamic` dont use it make use of `ObjectHandle`...as given in example

for unwrap check : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: How can I unwrap a type which I'm getting using reflection?

Comment: @user2822362 - you can use Unwrap method as i did

Comment: @user2822362 - you can also check here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I think there is some issues with my Assembly, Now it throws me cannot load type exception.

Comment: @user2822362 - ok dont forget to mark solution as accpeted if it works to solve your orignal problem related to this...